# avoiding a duplicate $(document).ready(function() tag

Tags: jquery

I am at a loss to explain why this snippet of code only works for the first function. The image swap fails to execute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function(){
// tip
    $("#tip").fancybox({
      'width'           : 420,
      'height'          : 300,
      'autoScale'       : true,
      'autoDimensions'  : true,
      'transitionIn'    : 'elastic',
      'transitionOut'   : 'fade',
      'overlayColor'    : '#111',
      'type'            : 'iframe'
    });
});
// image swap
$("#image1, #image2").click(function(){
  switch(this.id)
        {
        case 'image1':
          _(this.id,"../../img/answers.png","../../img/b13a(AC)ans.png");
          break;
        case 'image2':
          _(this.id,"../../img/answers(biggest4).png","../../img/b13b(AC)ans.png");
          break;
        }
    function _(id,main, alt){
        if($("#"+id).attr("src") == main) $("#"+id).attr("src", alt);
            else $("#"+id).attr("src", main);
    }
});
```

If I place the second function within a separate $(document).ready(function(), both routines work, but I'm trying to avoid the duplication.

Comment: You have earned the "Best Spaghetti Maker" badge.

Comment: I am unsure why you wrote that. Removing one line makes it work. The rest of the code seems neatly nested and essential. I could have cut it down, yes, but was afraid I might inadvertently remove what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to, `$(function(){})` is the same as `$(document).ready` :

```
$(function() {
// tip
    $("#tip").fancybox({
        'width'           : 420,
        'height'          : 300,
        'autoScale'       : true,
        'autoDimensions'  : true,
        'transitionIn'    : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut'   : 'fade',
        'overlayColor'    : '#111',
        'type'            : 'iframe'
    });
// image swap
    $("#image1, #image2").click(function(){
        switch(this.id) {
            case 'image1':
                _(this.id,"../../img/answers.png","../../img/b13a(AC)ans.png");
                break;
            case 'image2':
                _(this.id,"../../img/answers(biggest4).png","../../img/b13b(AC)ans.png");
                break;
        }
        function _(id,main, alt){
            if($("#"+id).attr("src") == main) $("#"+id).attr("src", alt);
                else $("#"+id).attr("src", main);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Now I understand! Simply removing the $(document).ready(function() tag did the trick!